# Let $(X,\tau)$ be a connected topological space, $Y\subset X$ connected and $U\subset X\setminus Y$ clopen. Prove that $ Y \cup U$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

Is the proof of the following exercise correct?

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a connected topological space, $Y\subset X$ connected and $U\subset X\setminus Y$ clopen. Prove that $ Y \cup U$ is connected.

Proof

As $Y$ is connected, $X\setminus Y$ is still connected.

As $U\subset X\setminus Y$ is clopen and $X$ is connected (there is only one clopen set, namely $X$), we must have this $U=X$.

And finally $Y\cup U=Y\cup X=X$ is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by seeing what's wrong with your proof by looking at an example:

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, Y = $\{0\}$, then $X$ is connected and so is $Y$. $X\setminus Y = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0,\infty)$ is disconnected (contrary to what you claim) and both sets are clopen in $X \setminus Y$ but are not clopen in $X$ (again a counterexample against your proof idea). Then the union of one of the clopens with $Y$ is either $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0]$ which are indeed connected, as claimed.

Sketch for a correct proof:

Start by writing $X \setminus Y = U \cup V$ where both $U$ and $V$ are disjoint clopen subsets of $X\setminus Y$. $V$ is just the relative complement of $U$, of course.

Now assume we can write $ Y \cup U = S \cup T$ where $S \cap T = \emptyset$ and $S,T$ clopen in $Y \cup U$ (so a relatively clopen partition of $Y \cup U$).

As $Y \subseteq Y \cup U$ is connected it must lie inside $S$ or $T$, so assume WLOG that $Y \subseteq S$.

Now $X = (V \cup S) \cup T$. To see this, let $x \in X$. If $x \in Y$ then $x \in S$ (done) or if $x \in X\setminus Y$, but then $x \in V$ (done) or $x \in U \subseteq Y \cup U$, so $x \in S$ or $x \in T$ (both cases means we're done).

Also $(V \cup S) \cap T = \emptyset$. This is clear, as $S$ and $T$ are disjoint by assumption, and any $x \in V$, cannot lie in $U$ or $Y$ so cannot be in $T$ either.

Now **you** have to check that $V \cup S$ and $T$ are clopen in $X$ and the first is non-empty, so $T = \emptyset$ and so $Y \cup U$ is connected.

Comment: Why to verify if $x \in U \subseteq Y \cup U$? Wouldn't be enough  to check if $ x\in Y$ and if $x\in X\setminus Y$?

Comment: @Ella that’s what I did. Clopenness is left to verify

Comment: $\ddot\smile $  I think I didn't write correctly, Why did you verify $x \in U \subseteq Y \cup U$? Why it's not enough just to check this: $x\in Y$    and $x\in X\setminus Y$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm so sorry, but your proof is wrong. $Y$ connected doesn't imply that $X\setminus Y$ is connected too. (Take the real line with the usual topology. The set $\{0\}$ is connected but $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ isn't).
Moreover, $U$ is clopen in the topology of subspace of $X\setminus Y$, not in the topology of $X$. You can't conclude that $U=X$