# Let $A$ be connected and $U$ be clopen in $Y-A$. Prove $A\cup U$ is connected. [Dugundji]

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This problem is on Topology - James Dugundji (1978), Chapter V (connectedness) Section 3, Problem 3. The problem says:

> Let $A\subset Y$, where both $A$ and $Y$ are connected. Let $U$ be any set both open and closed (clopen) in $Y-A$. Prove that $A\cup U$ is connected.

What I have recognized so far is:

- $Y-A$ is not connected by definition.
- $U$ is the union of its connected components by clopen's property.
- $A\cup B$ is connected if its connected component equals itself.

I don't know how to approach this problem using that properties.

Comment: This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595068/let-x-tau-be-a-connected-topological-space-y-subset-x-connected-and-u-s

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: Glad to help! ;)